# Why after this functions file_put_contents() line of code not executed?

Tags: php

i have created one function to upload image using web services.

```html
$image_url=time().$img_name;
$path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img';
$image_url_src=$path."/".$image_url;
$current = file_get_contents($image_url_src);
$current = base64_decode($img_url);
   
$res=file_put_contents($image_url_src,$current);
chmod($image_url_src, 0777);
if($res===true)
{
  $folder_img_url1="http://www.example.com/img/".$image_url;
  $auth_error=array("img_url" => $folder_img_url1); 
  return json_encode($auth_error);
}
```

Everything is working properly.. only problem is why not returning value after this line of code `file_put_contents($image_url_src,$current);`

if i return any value before file_put_contents function than it works but after calling `file_put_contents()` after that not return works so why?

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED

Comment: have your path is correct??? and any error you got??

Comment: Probably your call to `file_put_contents ()` is failing. Do you have write access where you're trying to put your file?

Comment: yes path is also correct and even image is also uploading in img folder also with 0777 permission..main problem is there is nothing display any error or nothing happen after uploding img to folder

Comment: Well, there are some errors that you yourself have to check for explicitly. I see one that you fail to handle.

Comment: i got the issue... because of this line of code getting problem "$current = file_get_contents($image_url_src);".. i have removed that code so now its working perfectly and returning value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code is works for me...

```
$image_url=time().$img_name;
$path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img';
$image_url_src=$path."/".$image_url;
//$current = file_get_contents($image_url_src); //this line of code is no need because of this not returning value..because it gives me an error.
$current = base64_decode($img_url);
$res=file_put_contents($image_url_src,$current);
//chmod($image_url_src, 0777);  if will remove than also its works
if($res===true)
{
  $folder_img_url1="http://www.example.com/img/".$image_url;
  $auth_error=array("img_url"   => $folder_img_url1); 
  return json_encode($auth_error);
}
```

Thank you for your time..

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with permission of folder

First give permission

```
<?php

chmod($image_url_src, 0777);
if (file_put_contents($image_url_src,$current)!== false) {
{
  $folder_img_url1="http://www.example.com/img/".$image_url;
  $auth_error=array("img_url"   => $folder_img_url1); 
  return json_encode($auth_error);
}
```

> This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the
>   file, or FALSE on failure. Meaning: file_put_contents will never
>   return TRUE. It will return false however, so if you were insistent on
>   using a boolean value then you would need to use:

Comment: file_put_contents function already working and in img folder newly uploading image also 0777 permission applied but want to return any msg after file_put_contents statement.... that is my issue

Comment: i got the issue... because of this line of code getting problem "$current = file_get_contents($image_url_src);".. i have removed that code so now its working perfectly and returning value